# "Can't find bundle for base name messages" error

Tags: java, jsf-2

while running my application I get the following error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /view/doi/common/navigation.xhtml: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale de_CH
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
```

In my faces-config I specified this:

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>messages</base-name>
  <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

and I have a directory src\web\resources\msg with the file messages_en.propeties.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the exception, the locale that the server is looking for is `de_CH` or failing that, `de`. If that fails too, then it will look for 'default' language, but what that is, depends on your system settings. So it may never even go to `messages_en.properties`. You could provide `messages.properties` instead (without any locale indicator) to serve as a default, if that's what you want.

Also read here for the full explanation of how the locale resolution works: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/

Comment: Yes, I forgot to have the messages.properties for the default values... Thanx