# Cant find resource bundle messages

Tags: java, jsf

This question is very similar (if not the same as):

["Can't find bundle for base name messages" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886729/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-messages-error)

[ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743433/resourcebundle-messages-not-found-for-messagesource-cant-find-bundle-for-bas)

Basically, i have this code:

```
<body>
<f:view>
<f:loadBundle basename="de.vogella.jsf.starter.messages" var="msg" />
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.user}"></h:outputLabel>
  <h:inputText value="#{user.name}">
  <f:validator
      validatorId="de.vogella.jsf.starter.validator.LoginValidator" />
  </h:inputText>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}"></h:outputLabel>
  <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}">
  </h:inputSecret>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton action="#{user.login}" value="#{msg.login}"></h:commandButton>
<h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>
</h:form>
</f:view>
```

And when I try to run, I get

```
An exception occurred processing JSP page /LoginView.jsp at line 13 
10: </head> 
11: <body> 
12: <f:view> 
13: <f:loadBundle basename="de.vogella.jsf.starter.messages" var="msg" /> 
14: <h:form> 
15: <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
16: <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.user}"></h:outputLabel> Stacktrace:

Caused by:
java.util.MissingResourceException - Can't find bundle for base name  de.vogella.jsf.starter.messages, locale en`
```

I tried to change file name, change file name in code, adding resource folder (but I think it was already properly included), and putting messages.properties file in all possible folders. Curiously, eclipse itself shows this error, it also has empty suggestion boxes for basename (no default proposals).
In case it helps, my project structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7VUF.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm if you have message.properties file in the directory `de.vogella.jsf.starter`?
If not please add the message.properties in this directory and then compile all. Check if you still get the exception?

Comment: AS you can see in the image I linked to, yes I have. The thing is de.vogella.jsf.starter is my project name.

Comment: @Xyzk, in the image i can see the message.properties in package `de.vogella.jsf.starter.model`? Please move the message.properties to `de.vogella.jsf.starter` or change your jsf file as `<f:loadBundle basename="de.vogella.jsf.starter.model.messages" var="msg" />`.

Comment: Actually I have copies of that file in all possible folders (effect of blindly searching for solution), but your alternative suggestion worked. Thank you. No idea why other did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. 
But finally, if you keep the messages.properties file under any package(de.vogella.jsf.starter.model) and include this as follows:
< f:loadBundle basename="de.vogella.jsf.starter.model.messages" var="msg" />
It is Working.